# Is there a quicker way to share a file with AirDrop on Mac?

Tags: macos, finder, file-sharing, airdrop

I love AirDrop and often share files between computers using it. This is how you do it on macOS:

1. Right-click on the file
2. Move the mouse all the way down to "Share" and click on it
3. Click on AirDrop
4. Finally, click on the device you want to share to

It's not that bad, but if you're doing this on a regular basis with multiple files it becomes *really* cumbersome.

Is there an easier way? I'm envisioning something like the device showing up on the Finder sidebar, and dragging the file onto it to automatically AirDrop it to that device—this would be an ideal scenario. Is there something like this? Or maybe an app which you can drag a file to, in order to share to a pre-chosen Mac?

Comment: An applescript where you just drop the file on it may be just yhe ticket - a similar script did batch copying or printing...

Comment: As far as I understand this envision is more or less built-in into Finder: [Use AirDrop on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203106) (Select AirDrop in the sidebar of a Finder window.  /../ The AirDrop window shows nearby AirDrop users. Drag one or more documents, photos, or other files to the recipient shown in the window.)

Comment: @AivarPaalberg actually you're right about this; this seems to be pretty much the fastest way of doing it, apart from creating an AppleScript which may not be worth the effort

Comment: I think that even with AppleScript it's hard to get any faster than ⌘⇧R.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use that shortcut when dragging a file, but at least you can drag it to the AirDrop menu, wait a tiny bit, and then drag it onto the target device